# ActiveMQ startup guide

Tags: activemq-classic

I am new to activeMQ. I want to make a simple application in which one EJB3 sends a message to ActiveMQ and its received and retrieved in MessageDrivenBean. There are so many possibilities to do that. And i an quite confused with so many example. Can anyone point to a good link for creating such application. I want to use ActiveMQ5.5.1 and JBoss6.0.0. And what are the known issues with this combination. 
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should start with some of the Fuse webinars/tutorials...

http://fusesource.com/enterprise-support/getting-started/

also, here is a guide to integrating AMQ/JBoss...

http://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

The first chapter to the [ActiveMQ in Action](http://bit.ly/2je6cQ) book is free and offers a good quick introduction.